# Angle brackets with an underset arrow

Tags: math-mode, boxes, arrows, brackets

I am trying to make a pair of angle brackets of variable height enclosing a main box along with a box beneath each bracket and an arrow of variable length between these lower boxes.  Since I'm sure that's extremely unclear, here are two hand-drawn (and a little crooked) examples of what I mean:

[image]

With my limited skills, here is the code I managed to produce:

```
\newcommand{\imfun}[3]{\underset{#1 \;-\hspace{-.1in} \hfill \rightarrow \; #3}{\sbox0{$#2$}
\mathopen{\resizebox{1.2\width}{\ht0}{$\Bigg\langle$}}
\usebox{0}
\mathclose{\resizebox{1.2\width}{\ht0}{$\Bigg\rangle$}}
}}
```

The three arguments are the three content boxes: lower left, main, and lower right.  In this implementation, the angle brackets do not change height gracefully and no attempt has been made to connect the head of the arrow to the tail.

I certainly appreciate any help you can offer!

Comment: nice question.  [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: If you use `$\left\langle$` and `$\right\rangle$` instead of the respective variants with `\Bigg`, then the brackets should scale with the content inside of them. The [LaTeX Wikibook entry](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Mathematics#Brackets.2C_braces_and_delimiters) on delimiters might be helpful.

Comment: @Adam Good tip!  A little stress test shows that the brackets have a maximum height that way, however.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The following example centers the left and right annotation text below the delimiters
and puts an extensible arrow between. The example uses package `amsmath` and
defines the following environments:

- Environment `amatrix` sets a matrix with angle brackets as delimiters, similar to environments `bmatrix`, `pmatrix` of package `amsmath`.
- Environment `amatrixarrow` takes one optional and two mandatory arguments and sets
  the annotations below the matrix connected by an arrow.

  ```
  \begin{amatrixarrow}[0.25ex]{left}{right} ... \end{amatrixarrow}
  ```

  The optional argument specifies the distance between matrix and annotation. The default is `0.5ex` of the annotation's font size and can be overwritten by the
  optional argument.

Example file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{amatrix}{%
  \left\langle
  \env@matrix
}{%
  \endmatrix
  \right\rangle
}

\newcommand{\amatrixarrow}[3][.5ex]{%
  \def\amatrixarrow@shift{#1}%
  \def\amatrixarrow@left{#2}%
  \def\amatrixarrow@right{#3}%
  \collect@body\amatrixarrow@next
}
\newcommand*{\amatrixarrow@next}[1]{%
  \mathpalette{\amatrixarrow@}{#1}%
}
\newcommand*{\amatrixarrow@}[2]{%
  % #1: math style (\displaystyle, \textstyle, ...)
  % #2: environment body
  \sbox0{$\m@th#1\begin{amatrix}#2\end{amatrix}$}%
  \sbox2{$\m@th#1\begin{matrix}#2\end{matrix}$}%
  \sbox4{$\m@th
    \amatrixarrow@style{#1}%
    \amatrixarrow@left
  $}%
  \sbox6{$\m@th
    \amatrixarrow@style{#1}%
    \amatrixarrow@right
  $}%
  \sbox8{$\m@th\amatrixarrow@style{#1}\text{\kern\amatrixarrow@shift}$}%
  \dimen0=.5\dimexpr\wd0-\wd2\relax
  \vtop{%
    \hbox{%
      \kern.5\dimexpr\wd4-\dimen0\relax
      % \fboxsep=0pt\fboxrule=.1pt \fbox{\copy0 }%
      \copy0 %
    }%
    \kern\wd8 %
    \nointerlineskip
    \hbox to \dimexpr\wd0+.5\wd4+.5\wd6-\dimen0\relax{%
      \copy4 %
      \hfill
      \sbox2{$\m@th
        \amatrixarrow@style{#1}%
        {}\xrightarrow{}{}%
      $}% shortest arrow with spacing
      $\m@th
        \amatrixarrow@style{#1}%
        \xrightarrow{%
          \kern\dimexpr\wd0-.5\wd4-.5\wd6-\dimen0-\wd2\relax
        }%
      $%
      \hfill
      \copy6 %
    }%
  }%
}
\newcommand*{\amatrixarrow@style}[1]{%
  \ifx#1\displaystyle
    \scriptstyle
  \else\ifx#1\textstyle
    \scriptstyle
  \else
    \scriptscriptstyle
  \fi\fi
  % #1%
}
%\renewcommand*{\amatrixarrow@style}[1]{#1}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\[
  {\begin{amatrixarrow}[0ex]{2\oplus 1\oplus 1}{4\oplus 2\oplus 4}
    bc - ad & bb - aa & ca + bd \\
    0       & b - a   & 0       \\
    0       & 2a      & 0
  \end{amatrixarrow}}
\Rightarrow
  {\begin{amatrixarrow}{3}{3\oplus 3}
    abc - acb & abc - bac
  \end{amatrixarrow}}
\]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

### Variant without decreased font size for annotation

I think the annotation looks better in a smaller math style. But it is possible to keep the current math style by changing the definition of `\amatrixarrow@style` to:

```
\newcommand*{\amatrixarrow@style}[1]{#1}
```

> [image: Result]

### Remarks (for the more experienced):

- The environment `amatrixarrow` catches its body by `amsmath`'s `\collect@body`.
  Then the environment contents can be used twice, in a `matrix` without delimiters and in `amatrix` with angle brackets. The horizontal position for the
  annotations are calculated by comparing the widths of the two matrices.
- By using `\vtop` with the matrix as first element, the reference point of the matrix remains unchanged. The annotations just enlarge the depth of the whole construct.
- `\mathpalette` provides the current math style.
- The reason for the optional parameter is, that it is not known, how many white space the matrix contains at the bottom. Internally the matrix is implemented using environment `array` that automatically adds invisible struts. The depth of the strut in the bottom line might increase the optical distance between the annotations and the bottom of the matrix, as seen in the first matrix of the example.
- In the example the environment `amatrixarrow` is put in curly braces to protect it from the parent environment `align*`.
- The arrow is drawn via `\xrightarrow` with the spacing of the arrow as relational
  symbol.

Answer (score 9):

This is not yet perfect but using `tikz`you can do so:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,calc}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (m)[matrix of math nodes,left delimiter={\langle},right delimiter={\rangle}]
    {  A  & B  & C+1  \\
       A' & B' &C' \\ };
\draw($(m.south west)-(0,0.1)$) node(a) {$x$};
\draw($(m.south east)-(0,0.1)$) node(b) {$y$};
\draw[->] (a)  edge (b);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

With result

[image]

Answer (score 6):

A slight improvement over @yann.pequignot's solution, using the `label` key to position texts under the backets. Note that since TikZ cannot make `&` given in the argument to an active character, `\&` is used instead as a column separator.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}

\newcommand\imfun[3]{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{
  every left delimiter/.style={
    xshift=1ex,label={[name=lb,label distance=-5pt,minimum height=2em]below:$#1$}
  },
  every right delimiter/.style={
    xshift=-1ex,label={[name=rb,label distance=-5pt,minimum height=2em]below:$#2$}
  }
}

\matrix [ampersand replacement=\&,matrix of math nodes,
left delimiter=\langle,right delimiter=\rangle]
{#3};
\draw[->](lb)--(rb);
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\imfun{2\oplus1\oplus1}{4\oplus2\oplus4}{
  bc-ad \& bb-aa \& ca+bd \\
  0 \& b-a \& 0 \\
  0 \& 2a \& 0 \\
}

\imfun{3}{3\oplus3}{abc-acb \& abc-bac\\}
\end{document}
```

[image]